# Alternative To Granger Causality?

Tags: correlation

Are there any other mathematical tests besides Granger that quants use to determine casual relations between two time series? If so what are they? How about [convergent cross mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_cross_mapping)?

Thanks

Comment: you can try transfer entropy

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: *Casual* relations?... For some reason this typo is pretty common in questions about causality. Might that be due to some naughty auto-correction routine? :)